# I'm having some problems regarding the data saving and the timer

Tags: timer, visual-studio-2017

My project is wind-powered racer system where there's 2 schools competing their own self made wind propeller attached to the given toy car kit. The fans and timers will turn on when the application starts.

These are my codes for the data saving part;

```
`string q = "SELECT * from Placing";
        cmd.CommandText = q;
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "*.csv ( comma separated value) |*.csv"; //save in what format
            sfd.OverwritePrompt = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                btnLaunch.Enabled = false;
                btnStart.Enabled = true;
                path = sfd.FileName; //path is where you save the file at
            }
            btnLaunch.Enabled = false;
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception etc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + etc.Message);
        }`

[Excel]`using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(MyProperty, true))

        {
            //write into excel file
            sw.WriteLine("RACE" + " " + racenumber1++ + "," + (cmbSch1.SelectedIndex + 1) + "," + cmbSch1.Text + "," + st1 + " " + "seconds" + "," + DateTime.Now);
            sw.WriteLine("RACE" + " " + racenumber2++ + "," + (cmbSch2.SelectedIndex + 1) + "," + cmbSch2.Text + "," + st2 + " " + "seconds" + "," + DateTime.Now);
            sw.Dispose();
        }`

[Timer]`TimeSpan elapsed = sw1.Elapsed;
        lblTimer1.Text = String.Format("{2:00}.{3:00}",
        Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours), elapsed.Minutes,
        elapsed.Seconds, elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
        st1 = lblTimer1.Text;`
```

[Screenshot of the application screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3T3v.png)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please provide details of the problem you are having? It is helpful if you provide details on your issue, what you have attempted already to fix it, and any other related information. Thanks!

Comment: Hey JamoBox, the problem I'm having is that the application has a problem running after running it once. As in, I try to run it once, everything goes well but after closing the application, the whole thing just breaks. For the timer,it usually starts a few seconds after I press the start button and if the sensor is being triggered on the right side, the left timer stops for awhile and then after maybe 5 seconds, it updates. Do you think its the codes problem or you think maybe my codes/application somehow got corrupted?